# Integrate Google Maps API in django template

Tags: django, google-maps

I have a query returning long/lat parameters of cities and would like to display a map in the template.
From Google's instructions, I cannot understand where to paste the javascript code.

I instead proceeded to do the following:

1. Created the map div in the html template (extended from base.html)
2. Pasted the script with API key in the javascript.html template
3. Added the javascript script in a map.js file in the static folder

Console shows: "initMap is not a function"
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

One good practise is to define a block at your base.html called *footer* just before closing the body element and load all js files/code in this content.

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
    {% block footercontent %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**yourtemplate.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block footercontent %}
       <script src="myscripts.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i looks like you probably copy the example script tag on the documentation, the error showing on the console means thers is no function named initMap. You see at hte end of the script tag src there is `&callback=initMap` where initMap is the name of the function to call when the google maps js files are ready to be use.

Maybe you din't import map.js of your static folder in your javascript.html template.

Pro tip: use `v=3` argument to have the stable version of the google maps api, like so ([more info](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)):

```
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3
    &key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
```